# преобразовать строку в int

Tags: python

У меня есть строка

```
s = "text"
```

я ее преобразовываю в hex

```
":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in s)
```

получаю строку

```
74:65:78:74
```

Как я могу преобразовать этот hex в десятичные числа?
т.е. ожидаю получить на выходе

```
116:101:120:116
```

Comment: а в hex обязательно преобразовывать? ord то же самое возвращает: `':'.join(str(ord(i)) for i in s)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструктор класса [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) позволяет передать вторым аргументом (`base`) основание системы счисления. Вы можете воспользоваться этим, чтобы получить объект числа, а затем его строковое представление в десятичной системе.

***Пример:***

```py
text = '74:65:78:74'

print(':'.join(str(int(h, 16)) for h in text.split(':')))
```

***stdout:***

```py
116:101:120:116
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'text'
res = ':'.join(map(str, str.encode(s)))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать короче, то есть использовать `hex`:

```
s = 'text'

num = ":".join(str(int(hex(ord(c)), 16)) for c in s)

print(num)
```

Вывод:

```
116:101:120:116
```

Comment: короче - не всегда лучше и тем более понятнее)